# Wordpress Category Pagination With Custom Permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I have a site with a permalink structure I can't change, which is `/blog/%category%/%postname%/` and I'm using `previous_posts_link()` and `next_posts_link()` to get pagination links. They work fine on date/all posts but not on category pages.

It's down to those links not having the right permalinks. They use `/blog/events/page/2/` which results in a 404 page, whereas if I use `/blog/category/events/page/2/`, they work.

So, ideally I'd like `/blog/events/page/2/` to work but if not then how can I get `next_posts_link()` to output the right links (`/blog/category/events/page/2/`)? Mindful of the fact I can't change the permalink structure, for seo purposes, apparently.

Here's the loop query:

```
        <?php 
        global $query_string;

        $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

        parse_str( $query_string, $args );

        $args['paged'] = $paged;

        query_posts($args); ?>

        <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

        <div id="post-results">

        <div class="pagination">

            <?php if (get_previous_posts_link()): ?>
                <span><?php previous_posts_link( 'Recent posts' ); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php if (get_next_posts_link()): ?>
                <span><?php next_posts_link( 'Previous posts' ); ?></span>
            <?php endif; ?>

        </div>

        ... rest of loop
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while working with plugin CPT UI custom post page template, and tried a lot to resolve the 404 page not found issue, Strangely the solution was quite simple, I just changes the permalink structure to "Numeric" and Voila it works!

Settings>>Permalinks>>Numeric